# What is causing this error: "Failed to retrieve package sources for XML"

Tags: r

What is causing this error: "Failed to retrieve package sources for XML"? I'm trying to publish an example dashboard to R Connect.

```
[Connect] 2020/12/10 16:40:00.827991448 Error in getSourceForPkgRecord(pkgRecord, srcDir(project), availablePackagesSource(repos = repos), : Failed to retrieve package sources for XML 3.99-0.5 from CRAN (internet connectivity issue?) [3.99-0.3 is current]

[Connect] Build error: A required R package was found in the package repository, but the specified version is not available. (r-package-version-not-available)
Application deployment failed with error: A required R package was found in the package repository, but the specified version is not available. (r-package-version-not-available)
```

I tried removing and then reinstalling XLM and recently updated my R to version 4.0.3. Wondering if that means I need to deprecate down to 3.99 for XML?

Repo info

```
> options('repos')
$repos
                       CRAN 
"https://cran.rstudio.com/" 
attr(,"RStudio")
[1] TRUE
```

Session info

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 4.0.3 (2020-10-10)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows >= 8 x64 (build 9200)

Matrix products: default

Random number generation:
 RNG:     Mersenne-Twister 
 Normal:  Inversion 
 Sample:  Rounding 
 
locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] shinydashboard_0.7.1       PerformanceAnalytics_2.0.4 xts_0.12.1                
[4] zoo_1.8-8                  highcharter_0.8.2          ggplot2_3.3.2             
[7] dygraphs_1.1.1.6           dplyr_1.0.2                shiny_1.5.0               

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] tidyselect_1.1.0  purrr_0.3.4       lattice_0.20-41   colorspace_2.0-0  vctrs_0.3.5      
 [6] generics_0.1.0    htmltools_0.5.0   yaml_2.2.1        rlang_0.4.9       later_1.1.0.1    
[11] pillar_1.4.7      glue_1.4.2        withr_2.3.0       TTR_0.24.2        lifecycle_0.2.0  
[16] quantmod_0.4.18   stringr_1.4.0     munsell_0.5.0     gtable_0.3.0      htmlwidgets_1.5.2
[21] labeling_0.4.2    fastmap_1.0.1     Cairo_1.5-12.2    httpuv_1.5.4      curl_4.3         
[26] broom_0.7.2       Rcpp_1.0.5        xtable_1.8-4      openssl_1.4.3     promises_1.1.1   
[31] scales_1.1.1      backports_1.2.0   jsonlite_1.7.1    farver_2.0.3      mime_0.9         
[36] askpass_1.1       digest_0.6.27     stringi_1.5.3     rlist_0.4.6.1     grid_4.0.3       
[41] quadprog_1.5-8    tools_4.0.3       magrittr_2.0.1    tibble_3.0.4      crayon_1.3.4     
[46] tidyr_1.1.2       pkgconfig_2.0.3   ellipsis_0.3.1    rsconnect_0.8.16  data.table_1.13.4
[51] lubridate_1.7.9.2 assertthat_0.2.1  rstudioapi_0.13   R6_2.5.0          igraph_1.2.6     
[56] compiler_4.0.3
```

Comment: I'm going to guess that your RSC instance is using R < 4.0. The 3.99-0.3 version of XML required `R (>= 2.13.0)`, whereas 3.99-0.5 requires `R (>= 4.0.0)`.

Comment: And to be clear, what version you are running locally is not always a clear indication of what is available on RSC.

Comment: I think the answer to one of your question is "yes", I think you need to downgrade your local version of `XML` to 3.99-0.3 and then attempt to push again to RSC. Or ask the RSC admins to make R-4.0 available.

Comment: Ok let me try that, thanks! My session info shows we're using R version 4.0.3 (2020-10-10)

Comment: And like I already said, what you are running locally *has no impact* on what RSC has available not-so-locally. When you push an app (shiny, plumber, etc) to RStudio Connect, if it has the exact same version of R available to the users as you are using locally, then it will be used, otherwise it will use the nearest match. I suggest you look at https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/226872207-Managing-R-versions-in-RStudio-Connect